# Set CSS Selector of child in Javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css

I have the following CSS Selector in an aura component:

```
.THIS .slds-grid:last-child .slds-col:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) lightning-formatted-text{
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
}

.THIS .slds-grid:last-child .slds-col:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd){
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

I want to be able to add them only when thisattribute is true:

```
<aura:attribute name="stretchLastField" type="Boolean"/>
```

The attribute value is changed in the design component.

How can i do this in Javascript\css?

**UPDATE**

This is the updated markup

```
<div class="{!'slds-grid full cols-2 forcePageBlockSectionRow'+(v.stretchLastField?'':' dont-stretch-last')}">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning:recordForm
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
                columns="2"
                fields="{!v.fieldsList != null ? v.fieldsList : ''}"
                mode="{!v.viewMode}" 
                onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}"
                onerror="{!c.onError}"
                oncancel="{!c.onCancel}"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.THIS .slds-grid.dont-stretch-last:last-child .slds-col:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) lightning-formatted-text{
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
    display: inline-block;
}

.THIS .slds-grid.dont-stretch-last:last-child .slds-col:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd){
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

i see it in the rendered element but its not applied to the last child
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to include an additional (custom) CSS class so that you can bind an expression somewhere:

```
.THIS .slds-grid.stretch-last:last-child .slds-col:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd) lightning-formatted-text{
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
}

.THIS .slds-grid.stretch-last:last-child .slds-col:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd){
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

Which you can then apply in markup:

```
<div class="{!'slds-grid'+(v.stretchLastField?' stretch-last':'')}">
  ...
```

Comment: the div that contains `slds-grid` is `<div class="slds-grid full cols-2 forcePageBlockSectionRow">`. How do i apply the same on that? can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @DanaGriff `{!'slds-grid full cols-2 forcePageBlockSectionRow'+(v.stretchLastField?' stretch-last':'')}` should do it. If for some reason not, it's probably a matter of a stray space somewhere. For example, if the div is top-most level, the selector should be `.THIS.slds-rid.stretch-last:last-child` ... (note, no space in there). You might also want to inspect the rendered element to make sure all style names are present.

Comment: i see it in the rendered element, but it's not applied to the last child, as the selector should.

Comment: @DanaGriff I just took a look, it appears that lightning-formatted-text is "display: inline;" Try adding an extra CSS attribute `display: inline-block;` to those two CSS rules, see if that fixes it.

Comment: didn't work, i have updated the question with the updated code

Comment: @DanaGriff Ah, I see now. You've run afoul of the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom). Basically, you're not allowed to tinker with the inside parts of a component in another namespace. You're probably not going to be able to achieve what you'd like without writing your own form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97870/discussion-between-dana-griff-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: Not really sure i understand why it works without the class dont-stretch-last, and why it doesn't with it.

Comment: cant i use querySelector for this, and the css in JS?